# No errors when loading Unity scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity 2019.4.31f1 (on it for reasons)

I have a Unity project that I have been working with successfully until suddenly I am getting this error with ALL of my GameObjects with scripts and I have no idea why:

[image]

I have ensured that the class name matches the filename:

[image]
[image]

I get no errors in the console. Only warnings because all of my scripts are failing:

[image]

When I remove a NuGet dependency I get an error in my script because the import no longer works (as I expect) but as soon as I add it back in, I get the no errors thing.

I am using these NuGet packages:

[image]

And these Unity packages:

[image]

My editor and UPM log show no errors.

How can I view the error? Is there a way to view the .NET compiler output?

Comment: Did the nuget packages work properly before?

Comment: Did your unity enter safe mode? And take a look at your upm.log.

Comment: @shingo On unity 2019 which I dont think has safe mode (cant upgrade)

Comment: The UPM log shows no errors

Comment: What .net profile did you choose?

Comment: @shingo 4.x.
So I tried creating a brand new project and add a script to a GameObject (with an empty scene), UPM and unity packages. Because it is empty scene I immediately got an error about missing GameObjects from my script (expected). When I comment out the bad line to fix the error, the console still shows the old console output! Weird.

Comment: (To add) Now I am getting the exact same script issue as I got originally in the new project.

Comment: Do you have assembly definitions that aren't including that file?